# Erro Qt: ASSERT failure in QList<T>

Tags: json, c++, loop, qt

Sou novo utilizando o Qt creator e atualmente estou trabalhando em um projeto para a faculdade e estou recebendo o seguinte erro

> ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range", file
>   ../../../../Qt485/imx28/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h,
>   line 477

trecho do Código QT

```
void page100::processarDados(){

    QString json = reply->readAll();
    QRegExp expretion("[{}]");      //expreçao regular
    QStringList Attribute;

    Attribute = json.split(expretion);


    QStringList elementRecord;
    QRegExp exp("[:,]");        //expreçao regular

    for(int i = 1; i< Attribute.size();i+=2){

        elementRecord = Attribute[i].split(exp);

        for(int j = 0; j <elementRecord.size(); j++){

            elementRecord = Attribute[i].split(exp);

            qDebug() << elementRecord[j];
        }

    }
}
```

Json que está sendo recebido

```
[
  {
    "idInstallation": 0,
    "project_Code": 0,
    "runId": 4,
    "block": "RUN_1",
    "input": "PLC_DigIn_1",
    "state": "1",
    "operation": true,
    "allDescription": null,
    "reducedDescription": "Test",
    "tstId": 0
  },
  {
    "idInstallation": 0,
    "project_Code": 0,
    "runId": 5,
    "block": "RUN_2",
    "input": "PLC_DigIn_2",
    "state": "1",
    "operation": true,
    "allDescription": null,
    "reducedDescription": "Test 2",
    "tstId": 0
  },
  {
    "idInstallation": 0,
    "project_Code": 0,
    "runId": 8,
    "block": "RUN_3",
    "input": "PLC_DigIn_3",
    "state": "1",
    "operation": true,
    "allDescription": null,
    "reducedDescription": "Test 3",
    "tstId": 0
  }
]
```

no primeiro **for** estou percorrendo de 2 em 2 para ignorar as virgulas que existem entre cada registro no meu json

o erro esta dando no segundo **for**, onde em cada registro percorro todos os elementos
EX: no registro 1

- elementRecord[0] = "idInstallation"
- elementRecord[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxeow.png) = 0
- elementRecord[2] = "project_Code"
- elementRecord[3] = 0
- elementRecord[4] = "runId"
- elementRecord[5] = 4
- elementRecord[6] = "block"
- elementRecord[7] = "RUN_1"
- elementRecord[8] = "input"
- elementRecord[9] = "PLC_DigIn_1"
- elementRecord[10] = "state"
- elementRecord[11] = "1"
- elementRecord[12] = "operation"
- elementRecord[13] = true
- elementRecord[14] = "allDescription"
- elementRecord[15] = null
- elementRecord[16] = "reducedDescription"
- elementRecord[17] = "Test"
- elementRecord[18] = "tstId"
- elementRecord[19] = 0

e assim para todos os outros registros.

mas não consigo identificar o erro.
alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Transcreva o json que você está recebendo direto pra pergunta.

Comment: Consegue explicar por palavras o que está a tentar fazer com essas expressões regulares ?

Comment: @Isac perdão pela falta de informação na pergunta , estou utilizando o Qt4.8 e nele não tenho suporte para trabalhar com Json, uma saída que tive foi tratar esse Json como String.

Estou utilizando expressões regulares para criar subStrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro indica que o index selecionado "não existe" dentro do vetor:

> index out of range

Mas estou respondendo não por isto, mas simplesmente porque não tem sentido usar expressão regular para um parse de JSON, entendo que o Qt4.8 não tenha suporte para `Json`, algo que só é suportado no Qt5: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

No entanto existem soluções, como:

- http://qjson.sourceforge.net

  Este precisa ser compilado antes de "linkar"
- https://github.com/eteran/qjson4

  Este funciona semelhante a API do Qt5, o que facilitaria em um port para novas versões do Qt5
- Solução mais provável, migrar para o Qt5

  Imagino que você deva ter instalado  o Qt4 porque vem nos repositórios, mas se optar por usar o Qt5 (ou o `eteran/qjson4`) você pode fazer assim:

  ```
  QString json = reply->readAll();

  QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json.toUtf8(), &error);

  if (error == QJsonParseError::NoError) {
       //Se o parse funcionar
  } else {
       qDebug() << error.errorString();
  }
  ```